# Using SELECT DISTINCT or alternative with a 3 table query

Tags: sql, select, distinct

Here I have an SQL statement which is retrieving all of the right stuff, but I need it to be DISTINCT.

So, for WEEK_NUMBER its returning week_number = 1,1,1,1,1,1 etc

I want it to condense into 1. It is a 3 table query and I'm not sure how I could include the SELECT DISTINCT feature or an alternative, any ideas??

```
SELECT WEEKLY_TIMECARD.*,DAILY_CALCULATIONS.*,EMPLOYEE_PROFILES.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
FROM WEEKLY_TIMECARD, DAILY_CALCULATIONS, EMPLOYEE_PROFILES 
WHERE EMPLOYEE_PROFILES.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = WEEKLY_TIMECARD.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
AND EMPLOYEE_PROFILES.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = DAILY_CALCULATIONS.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
AND WEEKLY_TIMECARD.WEEK_NUMBER = DAILY_CALCULATIONS.WEEK_NUMBER
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please tag your question with the SQL engine you are using.  Also, provide sample inputs and results.

Comment: Did you try just adding distinct to your query like this: `SELECT DISTINCT ...` ?

Comment: I wouldn't know where to put it, could you show me ? I did one before where it was SELECT DISTINCT WEEK_NUMBER AS W FROM .... But in this contenxt I wouldn't know what to do with the things before the 'FROM'

Comment: Which fields do you need in the output? just WEEK_NUMBER or some other fields as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT WEEKLY_TIMECARD.WEEK_NUMBER
FROM 
  WEEKLY_TIMECARD, 
  DAILY_CALCULATIONS, 
  EMPLOYEE_PROFILES 
WHERE EMPLOYEE_PROFILES.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = WEEKLY_TIMECARD.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
  AND EMPLOYEE_PROFILES.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = DAILY_CALCULATIONS.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
  AND WEEKLY_TIMECARD.WEEK_NUMBER = DAILY_CALCULATIONS.WEEK_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add `GROUP BY WEEK_NUMBER`

Comment: that will not work, as you need to group by all the output fields that are not in aggregate functions.

Comment: Well, I cannot argue with that )

Comment: Some SQL "dialects" may not let you do this, as they require that every output column is either a grouped column, an aggregate function or an expresion.

Comment: @Barranka Some dialects? Ok, I am really intrigued now ) Which ones will let you do this, just curious? And what will they output for fields that are not in group by or aggregate function?

Comment: @Adi, thanks! I will keep it in mind. This is not ANSI compliant and settings better be changed to avoid surprises.

Comment: @Bulat MSAccess is one... Yes, I know it may sound as a joke, but there are some people that use it (I am frequently forced to)

Comment: @Bulat By the way, which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Barranka I work with Oracle and Sql Server mainly, hence the confusion. Also question did not state the vendor, so I was thinking in ANSI terms sort of.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are showing all the fields from tables `WEEKLY_TIMECARD` and `DAYLY_CALCULATIONS`, if you use `SELECT DISTINCT...` you may end up with exactly the same situation you are encountering now (many rows with the same value).

Besides the `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` usage, you need to consider the following:

1. Do yo *really* need all the fields? If you do, then maybe you *do* need the duplicate values. If you don't, just include the fields you need.
2. Do you need to aggregate data? Or you only need to deduplicate the values? If you need to aggregate data, you *must* use `GROUP BY`, and the appropriate aggregating functions. If you don't need to aggregate data, I would advise you not to use `GROUP BY`, because it can make your query to be executed very slowly (it may depend on which RDBMBS you are using).
3. Whichever solution you choose, be sure your tables are properly indexed.

Besides that, I would use `INNER JOIN` to explicitly define the relations between your data (rather than implicitly defining them using `WHERE` conditions)... but that's my personal preference.